# Show InputGestureText as a tooltip for a Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tooltip, routed-commands

A have a `Button` with a `Command`. I want to display the `InputGestureText` as a `ToolTip` for every button that contains a command.

This is what I tried:

```
<n:ImageButton x:Name="NewRecordingButton" Text="Recording"        
   Command="util:Commands.NewRecording" 
   ToolTip="{Binding Source=util:Commands.NewRecording, Path=InputGestureText}" 
   ToolTipService.Placement="Top" ToolTipService.HorizontalOffset="-5"/>
```

I removed some elements for brevity.

I'm trying to achieve a similar result as a `MenuItem`. I want to display the shortcut if the user hovers the mouse on top of the button.

Comment: in place of Source , did you used the path property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MenuItem` has a property `InputGestureText`, when is not set it will check whether the item's `Command` is a `RoutedCommand` and will show the display string for the first `KeyGesture` it can find.

You can achieve the same thing via a converter (works only with `RoutedCommand`):

```
public class RoutedCommandToInputGestureTextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        RoutedCommand command = value as RoutedCommand;
        if (command != null)
        {
            InputGestureCollection col = command.InputGestures;
            if ((col != null) && (col.Count >= 1))
            {
                // Search for the first key gesture
                for (int i = 0; i < col.Count; i++)
                {
                    KeyGesture keyGesture = ((IList)col)[i] as KeyGesture;
                    if (keyGesture != null)
                    {
                        return keyGesture.GetDisplayStringForCulture(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:RoutedCommandToInputGestureTextConverter x:Key="RoutedCommandToInputGestureTextConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button 
        Content="Save"
        Command="Save" 
        ToolTip="{Binding Command, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource RoutedCommandToInputGestureTextConverter}}" 
        ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: When I try this it gives a binding error, " 'Command' property not found on 'object' ", as soon as the Window loads. It must be a timing thing, because if I do the Binding in code in the Window's Loaded event handler, it works fine.